# Set time also on a textfield after setting the date

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting a date on my text field like so...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   showDatePicker()
  }

 func showDatePicker() {

    datePickerStartDate.datePickerMode = .date

    datePickerStartDate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EventDetailViewController.startDatePickerSelect(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    startDateTextfield.inputView = datePickerStartDate

  }

 @objc func startDatePickerSelect(sender: UIDatePicker)  {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium

    startDateTextfield.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

  }
```

This opens a datepicker on tap on the textfield and sets the date. But what I want is after I select the date, I want the time picker also to show up so that I can set the time also. And this time should get appended to the date that was set initially. How can I achieve that..?

Comment: what was the OP you expect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik OP = Original Post or Original Poster

Comment: What is your question about, merging the results from the two pickers or how to present the time picker after the date picker?

Comment: I want to present the time picker after the date picker and then merge the date and time together @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yes but which part is your question about?

Comment: What I showed in the question is the part where I display the date picker and assign the selected date to the textfield. But soon after the date is displayed, I want the time picker also to show up from where I can select the time and then once the time is selected, both the date and time should be displayed on the textfield together @JoakimDanielson

Comment: You keep saying the same thing so I assume you want help with both but I don't know how to handle the first part so hopefully someone else can provide you with a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
```

You can get the time of your choice from the string as :

```
let timeStr = "2:00"
var time = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeStr)
```

Or you can add and subtract specific time from the current date as :

`//It will give you the time by adding 5 minutes to the current time you can use (-5*60) to get the time 5 minute back.`

```
var date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(5*60))
var timeStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```